# handle null from database

Tags: .net, vb.net, null, sqldatareader

I need to round and print a price like below, but this does not handle null values.
How can I handle null values on one line of code?
DBRSet is an *SQLDataReader* and the price is *money* type in SQL.

```
<%= Math.Round(DBRSet("price"))%>
```

I have about 200 .aspx pages of this so I could also use some tips on how to change these in an easy way?  Can I do a search and replace with a reg-exp or something like that?

Comment: How can `DBRSet` be a `SQLDataReader` when you use it like method call?

Comment: Or is it VB.NET? In that case, don't you need a cast to `decimal`? DataReader indexer returns `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle the `DbNull` case explicitly, for example:

```
<%= DbNull.Equals(DBRSet["price"]) ? "null" : Math.Round(DBRSet["price"]).ToString() %>
```

This is unwieldy, so it makes sense to have a helper method something like this somewhere:

```
static class FormatDbValue {
    public static string Money(object value)
    {
        if (DbNull.Equals(value)) {
             return "0";
        }

        return Math.Round((decimal)value);
    }
}
```

Which would allow

```
<%= FormatDbValue.Money(DBRSet["price"]) %>
```

Of course finding and changing all such code to use the helper method would be... unpleasant. I would do it by searching throughout the project (maybe in smaller chunks of the project) for something indicative (maybe `Math.Round`?) and review it manually before replacing.

Comment: Ah, this will probably work. It's not a typo though, it works.

Comment: I'll do the helper method thing, so this will be the best answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the aspx's, but can easily change the definition of the `DBRSet` property, you can put there a wrapper over the `SqlDataReader` and implement your own indexer that would first check for null and go into the inner `dataReader` to get the value if not null.